# Magento database migration from 1.6 to 1.9 errors

Tags: php, mysql, magento, upgrade

I've made a fresh install with Magento 1.9 version and moved the files from 1.6 to 1.9 project as the tutorials shows. I removed the fresh installed 1.9 database tables and then uploaded the 1.6 old database. When I try to run the project I get the next errors:

```
Error in file: "D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view `enter code here`already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_group_price` (
  `value_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Value ID' ,
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `all_groups` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT 'Is Applicable To All Customer Groups' ,
  `customer_group_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Customer Group ID' ,
  `value` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Value' ,
  `website_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE `CC12C83765B562314470A24F2BDD0F36` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_GROUP_PRICE_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_GROUP_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_GROUP_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DF909D22C11B60B1E5E3EE64AB220ECE` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Group Price Attribute Backend Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below steps for upgrade magento.

1. Upload your old database in your localhost.
2. Copy and Paste magento 1.9 version fresh copy in your htdocs folder.
3. Now from your 1.6.2.0 merge your following custom folders into the 1.9

   - Community app/code/community
   - Local app/code/local
   - Media
   - your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/ or
     app/design/frontend/)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current
     app/etc/modules/
   - any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
   - copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.6.2.0) to
     adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
   - custom js files if any from app/js/.
4. Now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
5. Check the site in the browser. it is done.